# Como remover um input tipo select do serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

- > Bom dia Galera! ótima sexta-feira!!

Estou com uma duvida aqui estou pegando todos os dados de um formulário

```
$.post("salvar_1.php", $("#form").serialize())
```

Mais preciso remover um select com o nome **data**, do serialize, e outra coisa no final eu **passo todos os dados por $_GET** com

```
var str = $('#data').val() + decodeURIComponent($( "form" ).serialize());
    window.location.replace(str);
```

Está parte eu consegui tirar, o @40 do '@' para emails, mais os espaços continuam vindo como %20... eu consigo retirar isso preciso da url limpa no final! e sem a **variável data do select!**

Comment: Bom dia vlwho,séria legal mostra como está os valores, como está a url completa, como o valor está no select e como ele está indo para o servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vinícius, acho que você deveria passar os dados por POST, entretanto, para resolver rapidamente seu problema, vc poderia utilizar o seletor `:not()`. Ficaria assim:

`$('form :not(select#data)').serialize();`

ou utilizando o name do select ao invés do id:

`$('form :not(select[name="data"])').serialize();`

O que seria o equivalente a: selecione todo o formulário menos o que tiver o id (ou o name="data") especificado.

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou agora como eu retiro %20 do espaços tentei assim e nao funcionou!

   var str = $('#data').val() + decodeURIComponent($('form :not(select[name="data"])').serialize());
              novaString = str.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
     window.location.replace(novaString);

Comment: Vinícius, o `%20` do espaço não deve ser retirado! a URL quebra pois você está passando os dados via GET, o tratamento para reverter esses caracteres especiais deve ser feito a aplicação que recebe os dados!

Comment: Intendi, obrigado!